# Why my for loop isn't working right for the menus in tkinter python

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

[out put](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uViN.png)I just want to make sure that the label and command should work properly

```
list = {'About', 
'Experience'}
comand = ['about','experience']
for i in range(len(list)):
    for t in range(len(comand)):
        help_menu.add_command(label=str(i), command=str(t))
```

I also have tried this

```
list = {'About', 
'Experience'}
comand = ['about','experience']
for i in range(len(list)):
    for t in range(len(comand)):
        help_menu.add_command(label='list'+str(i), command='comand'+str(t))
```

Comment: What are the texts you want to have in the menu?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it isn't working is because you are using a nested for loop.  By nesting the for loops you are essentially looping through that many times more than you want to.  Try just using a single for loop that assigns the value from both lists using the single index.

I think you are trying to do this:

```
lst = ['About', 'Experience']
comand = [about,experience]
for i in range(len(list)):
    help_menu.add_command(label=lst[i], command=comand[i])
```